# Open Sans thin (weight 200) from google

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I am trying to get the "thin" version of the Open Sans font - marked as weight 200. See: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

I have defined the font weight as 200, but it seems like i cannot get below 300.

I get the stylesheet like this: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't go below 300.. min font-weight for this font is 300

```
Light 300
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Light 300 Italic
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Normal 400
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Normal 400 Italic
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Semi-Bold 600
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Semi-Bold 600 Italic
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Bold 700
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Bold 700 Italic
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Extra-Bold 800
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
Extra-Bold 800 Italic
Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack.
```

Comment: The designer of Open Sans never did thinner version than 300. If you need it more thin, you need to create the required font yourself. I think font open source tool called fontforge can be used for the job: https://fontforge.github.io/Styles.html